# Enterprise Architect: Line break in name of connectors

Tags: enterprise-architect

I want to structure a very long label of a connector (to be more precise: guard of a transition in a state diagram) by inserting line breaks. Line breaks appear when I change the width of the label but I want to control the position of the line breaks.
In an element, e.g. a "state", I can click twice on the name and then I can edit the name and insert line breaks with Ctrl+Enter. But that doesn't work for connectors.

I'm using Enterprise Architect 10

Comment: Are you telling us there's a bug in EA, or do you actually have a question as well?

Comment: My question is if there is a possibility to insert a line break into the label of a connector. Maybe I haven't expressed that clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that is not possible.
If you want to request that feature you can send a [feature request](http://sparxsystems.com/support/forms/feature_request.html) to Sparx Systems

Comment: Thank you. I have sent a request for that feature to Sparx Systems

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using nonbreaking space. Use nonbreaking space instead of regular space and use regular space instead of line break.

There isn't a shortcut for a nonbreaking space character so copy it from a text editor.